# is my Enumeration correct?

Tags: java, enums, correctness

All over our project, we have this kind of enums. They works just fine, but we are not sure about them.

Specially with the getDocumentType(String) method.

Is there a way to avoid the iteration over all the Enums field ?

```
public enum DocumentType {

    UNKNOWN("Unknown"),
    ANY("Any"),
    ASSET(Asset.class.getSimpleName()),
    MEDIA(Media.class.getSimpleName()),
    MEDIA35MM(Media.class.getSimpleName() + " 35mm");


    private String label;

    private DocumentType(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public static DocumentType getDocumentType(String label){
        for(DocumentType documentType : DocumentType.values()){
            if(documentType.getLabel().equals(label)){
                return documentType;
            }
        }
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Edit : 
Check the newacct response. She's fine too.

Comment: It's tempting to store a static Map of labels to enum instances, but frustratingly, java won't let you reference a static field from an enum's constructor.

Comment: I wonder why do you use Asset.class.getSimpleName() instead of just writing "Asset" ? Do you plan to change the name by refactoring?

Comment: Because it's always good practice to use class literals instead of strings?

Comment: @skaffman: Okay, then why aren't there an Unknown and Any class?

Comment: Because you don't invent a class just so you can refer to its name, but if the class already exists, then use the literal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get enum by its inner field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780129/get-enum-by-its-inner-field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have to do that iteration somewhere, due to the restrictions in writing enums. In an ideal world, you would populate a static Map from within DocumentType's constructor, but that's not allowed.

The best I can suggest is performing the iteration once in a static initializer, and storing the enums in a lookup table:

```
public enum DocumentType {

    .... existing enum stuff here

    private static final Map<String, DocumentType> typesByLabel = new HashMap<String, DocumentType>();
    static {
        for(DocumentType documentType : DocumentType.values()){
            typesByLabel.put(documentType.label, documentType);
        }
    }

    public static DocumentType getDocumentType(String label){
        if (typesByLabel.containsKey(label)) {
            return typesByLabel.get(label);
        } else {
            return UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
}
```

At least you won't be doing the iteration every time, although I doubt you'll see any meaningful performance improvement.

Comment: I just spent 10 minutes or so shouting at the compiler

Comment: If there are are 100's of elements in the enum (or even <ugh> thousands) then this might be a performance improvement ... might, especially if you are looking these up a lot.

Comment: And store it where? EnumMap is just an optimized Map, it's not magic.

Comment: Sorry, I had in my head Enum->AlternateNameString, which is backwards from what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (For what it's worth), that is the best way to do what you want.

That is how I would do it at least.

If your `enum` count grows significantly (couple hundred - thousands) you may want to add a `Map`ing of `Strings` to `enums` to do the look-up a little faster.  But for the small amount of `eunums` you have, this may be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me.

I'd leave the iteration as it is. Sure you could add a Map<'label','DocumentType'> implementation to the enum class and do a lookup but it won't increase performance significantly.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are known at compile-time, and if they are valid identifiers, you can just use them as the names of the enums directly:

```
public enum DocumentType { Unknown, Any, Asset, Media, Media35mm }
```

and then get it by `.valueOf()`. For example:

```
String label = "Asset";
DocumentType doctype;
try {
    doctype = DocumentType.valueOf(label);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    doctype = DocumentType.Unknown;
}
```

Comment: A colleague was comming with the same solution. It's fine for most of the time, not in our precise case, but for next iteration will will check if we really nead a identifier and a label.