# Getting Enum value by another value

Tags: java, enums

I have the following `enum` that contains two values, a string identifier and a boolean valid status. I would like to be able to get the status value by using the string identifier.

Has anyone got any suggestions what I can add to the code below?

```
public enum MyEnum {

    TYPEA("001", true),
    TYPEB("002", false);
    
    private final String identifier;
    private final boolean valid;

    MyEnum(String identifier, boolean valid) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.valid = valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the enum type by its attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888560/how-to-get-the-enum-type-by-its-attribute)

Comment: No, I am trying to get an enum value by another enum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ENUM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) types has the method `values`, which you can use to extract all the enum values and compare their identifier against the one that you have passed by the method parameter, namely:

```
public MyEnum getEnum(String identifier){
      for(MyEnum e : MyEnum.values())
         if(e.identifier.equals(identifier))
            return e;
      return null;
 }
```

or even better:

```
public static Optional<MyEnum> getEnum(String identifier){
        return Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).filter(i -> i.identifier.equals(identifier)).findFirst();
}
```

This way you make it clear on the method signature that you might or not find the enum.

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum MyEnum {

   TYPEA("001", true),
   TYPEB("002", false);

   private final String identifier;
   private final boolean valid;

   MyEnum(String identifier, boolean valid) {
       this.identifier = identifier;
       this.valid = valid;
   }

   public static MyEnum getFromIdentifier(String identifier) {
       return Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).filter(item -> item.identifier.equals(identifier)).findFirst().orElse(null);
   }
}
```