# How can i create Enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I already created Enum. But i cannot create **new Enum**. I wanna create and compare 2 Enums actually. The X value is coming from backend. It's a dynamic value. I wanna make this;

```
EmployeeType type = new EmployeeType("X")

if (type == EmployeeType.X_PERSONALS) {
    Log.i("SAMPLE_TAG", "Yesss!")
}
```

```
public enum EmployeeType {
    X_PERSONALS("X"),
    Y_PERSONALS("Y"),
    Z_PERSONALS("Z");

    private final String text;

    EmployeeType(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: "But i cannot create new Enum" this is literally the point of enums: you can't instantiate them. You can refer to the existing elements, like `EmployeeType type = EmployeeType.X_PERSONALS;`.

Comment: "X" value is coming from backend. It's a dynamic value.

Comment: Then what you are looking for is probably: [How to get the enum type by its attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888560/how-to-get-the-enum-type-by-its-attribute/30212636)

Comment: But you should include that information in your question, not in a comment. That information is vital to understand what you actually have problems with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you are actually trying to achieve is to find the enum constant that has the same `text`. You can to that like this:

```
public enum EmployeeType {
    X_PERSONALS("X"),
    ///...and so on

    public static EmployeeType getByText(String x) {
        for(EmployeeType t:values()) {
            if(t.text.equals(x)){
                return t;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then use the code like this:

```
EmployeeType type = EmployeeType.getByText("X");
if (type == EmployeeType.X_PERSONALS) {
    //and so on
```

Comment: You can also build a `Map<String, EmployeeType>` if you are going to do this lookup a lot.

Comment: I know that OP's enum is probably only an example, but with 3 constants I would probably advise against using a Map.

Answer (score 4):

> But i cannot create new Enum

This is literally the point of enums: you can't instantiate them.

You can refer to the existing elements e.g.

```
EmployeeType type = EmployeeType.X_PERSONALS;
```