# Decode Java enum from single char

Tags: java

I have

> No enum constant [...] at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)

when I try to decode a single char string to an enum.

What is wrong, how can I fix it?

```
public class testEnum {

    public enum Colors {
        RED("R"), GREEN("G"), BLUE("B");
        private final String code;

        Colors(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Colors c = Colors.valueOf("R");
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

In this case, I expect `RED` to the ouput console.

Comment: How does Java know that `R` corresponds to the `code` field?

Answer (score 3):

`Colors.valueOf("R")` is a implicitly declared method and a shortcut of `Enum.valueOf(Colors.class, "R")`.

[The documentation of `Enum.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)) states

> @param `name` the name **of the constant** to return

Your constants are `RED`, `GREEN`, and `BLUE`.

[You may wanna get an enum instance by its field.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780129/get-enum-by-its-inner-field)

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong, how can I fix it?

Java has no way of knowing that you're trying to pass a value of the `code` field to look up.

To fix it, either specify the entire name:

```
Colors.valueOf("RED")
```

or construct a `Map<String, Colors>` that you can look up instances from.

```
Map<String, Colors> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Colors colors : Colors.values()) {
  map.put(colors.code, colors);
}
// Assign to a field somewhere.

// Then, later:
Colors c = map.get("R");
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of the method you have invoked:

```
valueOf:
Returns the enum constant of this type with the specified name. The string must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum constant in this type. (Extraneous whitespace characters are not permitted.)
Returns:
the enum constant with the specified name
```

In your case, enum 'name' will be "RED", "GREEN" or "BLUE". or if you want to refer to your enum it's Colors.RED.name()

If you want to lookup the Colors enum that corresponds to the code, what you can do is to have something like this:

```
public class Sampler {
    public enum Colors {
        RED("R"), BLUE("B"), GREEN("G");

        private static final Map<String, Colors> COLORS_MAP;

        static {
            COLORS_MAP = new HashMap<>();
            for(Colors color : values()) {
                COLORS_MAP.put(color.code, color);
            }
        }

        private final String code;

        Colors(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public static Colors fromCode(String code) {
            return COLORS_MAP.get(code);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Colors c = Colors.fromCode("R");
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My decision

```
public enum Colors {
    RED("R"), GREEN("G"), BLUE("B");
    private final String code;

    Colors(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static Colors ofCode(String code){
        Colors[] values = Colors.values();
        for (Colors value : values) {
            if(value.code.equals(code)){
                return value;
            }

        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Code not found"); 
    }

}
```