# Avoiding multiple If statements in Java

Tags: java

I've coded a method something like this. But I guess this should undergo refactoring.
Can any one suggest the best approach to avoid using this multiple if statements?

```
private String getMimeType(String fileName){
  if(fileName == null) {
    return "";   
  } 
  if(fileName.endsWith(".pdf")) {
    return "application/pdf";   
  }
  if(fileName.endsWith(".doc")) {
    return "application/msword";  
  }
  if(fileName.endsWith(".xls")) {
    return "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
  }
  if(fileName.endsWith(".xlw")) {
    return "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
  }
  if(fileName.endsWith(".ppt")) {
    return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; 
  }
  if(fileName.endsWith(".mdb")) {
    return "application/x-msaccess"; 
  }
  if(fileName.endsWith(".rtf")) {
    return "application/rtf"; 
  }
  if(fileName.endsWith(".txt")) {
    return "txt/plain"; 
  }
  if(fileName.endsWith(".htm") || fileName.endsWith(".html")) {
    return "txt/html"; 
  }
  return "txt/plain"; 
}
```

I cannot use switch-case here as my 'condition' is a `java.lang.String`.

Comment: PS the correct text MIME types are like "text/html", "text/plain"

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199646/long-list-of-if-statements-in-java/1199879#1199879

Comment: @Rich: very similar but not exactly the same. The different cases here don't have structurally different code. Only simple value assignments, which make the problem (and the solutions) simpler.

Comment: This isn't what you are asking, but it bothers me that html files with extension .php or .jsp will be labeled "txt/plain."

Comment: Using this implementations, adding a mime type requires recompiling, instead of a change in properties file

Comment: In Java 7, you can use `String`s as `switch` cases.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to hold your solutions:

```java
Map<String,String> extensionToMimeType = new HashMap<String,String>();
extensionToMimeType.put("pdf", "application/pdf");
extensionToMimeType.put("doc", "application/msword");
// and the rest

int lastDot = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
String mimeType;
if (lastDot == -1) {
    mimeType = NO_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE;
} else {
    String extension = fileName.substring(lastDot+1);
    mimeType = extensionToMimeType.getOrDefault(extension, 
                                                UNKNOWN_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE);
}
```

For this code to work you'll need to have defined `NO_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE` and `UNKNOWN_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE` as in your class, somewhat like this:

```java
private static final String NO_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE = "application/octet-stream";
private static final String UNKNOWN_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE = "text/plain";
```

Comment: paste results in compilation errors... can't find NO_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE or UNKNOWN_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE. Plz Hlp :-)

Comment: @extraneon: those are left as an exercise for the reader and depend on the specification.

Comment: @extraneon: Add `private static final NO_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE = "application/octet-stream";` and `private static final UNKNOWN_EXTENSION_MIME_TYPE = "application/octet-stream";` to the top of your class. Change `application/octet-stream` to whatever **you** want to use for the *no extension* and *unknown* MIME types.

Comment: Its just removing if from code but introducing it inside HashMap or Map. This is not really a solution in my view.

Answer (score 11):

Using a [HashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) perhaps?

This way you could do `myMap.get(mystr);`

Comment: but he needs `endsWith`, `get` uses an exact match

Comment: @dfa: he's matching a file suffix ... stuff after the last ".".

Comment: @Stephen C: exactly, you can just get everything after the last "." by using things like `LastIndexOf`.

Comment: @Stephen: `myMap.get(".pdf) != fileName.endsWith(".pdf")`; he needs at least to extract the extension first

Comment: @dfa: I think we can assume that the OP has the intelligence to figure out how to take the suffix a String.

Answer (score 5):

Command pattern is the way to go. Here is one example using java 8:

**1. Define the interface:**

```
public interface ExtensionHandler {
  boolean isMatched(String fileName);
  String handle(String fileName);
}
```

**2. Implement the interface with each of the extension:**

```
public class PdfHandler implements ExtensionHandler {
  @Override
  public boolean isMatched(String fileName) {
    return fileName.endsWith(".pdf");
  }

  @Override
  public String handle(String fileName) {
    return "application/pdf";
  }
}
```

and

```
public class TxtHandler implements ExtensionHandler {
  @Override public boolean isMatched(String fileName) {
    return fileName.endsWith(".txt");
  }

  @Override public String handle(String fileName) {
    return "txt/plain";
  }
}
```

and so on .....

**3. Define the Client:**

```
public class MimeTypeGetter {
  private List<ExtensionHandler> extensionHandlers;
  private ExtensionHandler plainTextHandler;

  public MimeTypeGetter() {
    extensionHandlers = new ArrayList<>();

    extensionHandlers.add(new PdfHandler());
    extensionHandlers.add(new DocHandler());
    extensionHandlers.add(new XlsHandler());

    // and so on

    plainTextHandler = new PlainTextHandler();
    extensionHandlers.add(plainTextHandler);
  }

  public String getMimeType(String fileExtension) {
    return extensionHandlers.stream()
      .filter(handler -> handler.isMatched(fileExtension))
      .findFirst()
      .orElse(plainTextHandler)
      .handle(fileExtension);
  }
}
```

**4. And this is the sample result:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MimeTypeGetter mimeTypeGetter = new MimeTypeGetter();

    System.out.println(mimeTypeGetter.getMimeType("test.pdf")); // application/pdf
    System.out.println(mimeTypeGetter.getMimeType("hello.txt")); // txt/plain
    System.out.println(mimeTypeGetter.getMimeType("my presentation.ppt")); // "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
  }
```

Comment: Small suggested improvement - you can omit the String fileName argument from the handle method of ExtensionHandler.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I don't have problems with the if statements. The code is readable, it took just milliseconds to understand what you're doing. It's a private method anyway and if the list of mime types is static then there's no urgent need to move the mapping to a properties file and use a lookup table (map). Map would reduce lines of code, but to understand the code, then you're forced to read the code and the implementation of the mapping - either a static initializer or an external file.

You *could* change the code a bit and use an enum:

```
private enum FileExtension { NONE, DEFAULT, PDF, DOC, XLS /* ... */ }

private String getMimeType(String fileName){
  String mimeType = null;

  FileExtension fileNameExtension = getFileNameExtension(fileName);

  switch(fileNameExtension) {
    case NONE:
      return "";
    case PDF:
      return "application/pdf";

    // ...

    case DEFAULT:
      return "txt/plain";   
  }

  throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled FileExtension detected");
}
```

The `getFileNameExtension(String fileName)` method will just return the fitting enum value for the fileName, `FileExtension.NONE` if fileName is empty (or null?) and `FileExtension.DEFAULT` if the file extension is not mapped to a mime type.

Answer (score 4):

what about using **a MIME detection library** instead?

- [mime-util](http://www.medsea.eu/mime-util/)
- [mime4j](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/)
- JMimeMagic library - Free. Uses file extension and magic headers to determine MIME type.
- mime-util - Free. Uses file extension and magic headers to determine MIME type.
- DROID (Digital Record Object Identification) - Free. Uses batch automation to detect MIME types.
- Aperture Framework - Free. A framework for crawling external sources to identify MIME types.

(feel free to add more, there so many libraries..)

Answer (score 2):

I consider your approach to be the best overall. This comes after having tested with a number of different approaches myself.

I see a number of huge benefits in your current approach, namely:

1. Easily **readable and understandable** by anyone (in my experience, medium-level programmers often underestimate this and usually prefer going with fancy-patterns which, in the end are not readable at all for the vast majority of programmers who do not know that specific pattern)
2. All the **information is in one single place**. As Andreas_D pointed out, hunting around  files or classes is not a good option for someone that needs to fix a bug while you are on holiday!
3. Easily **maintainable**: I could "F3" (if you are Eclipse-ing) on the method and add a new content type in seconds without any worries of introducing bugs!

I can suggest a few things anyway:

1. This method is very general purpose:
   Why should it be private?! This is a
   **public method** of some utility/helper class!
   Moreover it should be a **static method**!! You don't need anything
   from    the Object itself to perform
   your    job!
2. You could use **indenting** to make
   things prettier and compact. I know
   that indenting is some kind of
   religion for the most of us, but I
   think it should not be a strict rule;
   it should be properly used to make
   our code more **readable and compact**.
   If this would be a config file you
   would probably have something like:

> ```
> pdf=application/pdf
> doc=application/msword
> ```

You could have a very similar result with:

```
    public static String getMimeType(String fileName){
       if(fileName == null) return "";
       if(fileName.endsWith(".pdf")) return "application/pdf";
       if(fileName.endsWith(".doc")) return "application/msword";
       if(fileName.endsWith(".xls")) return "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
       return "txt/plain"; 
   }
```

This is also what a lot of the Map based implementations look like.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to evade that in general. In your case - if there is a set of allowed extensions - you could create an Enum, convert the extension to the Enum type via valueOf(), and then you can switch over your enum.

Comment: Yeah... I would go for those HashMaps too, now that I thought it over :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by putting the associations in a map, and then using the map for lookup:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put(".pdf", "application/pdf");
map.put(".doc", "application/msword");
// ... etc.

// For lookup:
private String getMimeType(String fileName) {
    if (fileName == null || fileName.length() < 4) {
        return null;
    }

    return map.get(fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 4));
}
```

Note that using the `switch` statements on strings is one of the proposed new features for the next version of Java; see [this page](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_strings_in_switch) for more details and an example of how that would look in Java 7:

```
switch (fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 4)) {
    case ".pdf": return "application/pdf";
    case ".doc": return "application/msword";
    // ...
    default: return null;
```

(edit: My solution assumes the file extension is always 3 letters; you'd have to change it slightly if it can be longer or shorter).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and shortest way for this particular problem would be using the builtin Java SE or EE methods.

Either in "plain vanilla" client application (which derives this information from the underlying platform):

```
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(filename);
```

Or in a JSP/Servlet web application (which derives this information from the `web.xml` files):

```
String mimeType = getServletContext().getMimeType(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a Groovy class here as it allows for switch-case on Strings :)

Answer (score 0):

How about mapping the extensions to MIME types, then using a loop? Something like:

```
Map<String,String> suffixMappings = new HashMap<String,String>();
suffixMappings.put(".pdf", "application/pdf");
...

private String getMimeType(String fileName){
    if (fileName == null) {
        return "";   
    }
    String suffix = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    // If fileName might not have extension, check for that above!
    String mimeType = suffixMappings.get(suffix); 
    return mimeType == null ? "text/plain" : mimeType;
 }
```

Comment: Why bother with a Map if you're simply going to loop over it?  Would be better to strip the suffix and perform an ~O(1) direct look-up.

Comment: a better strategy here is to extract the extension (filename.ext -> ext) and do a lookup with suffixMappings

Comment: for iterating it would probably better to loop over the entrySet() in order to avoid the second lookup by get().

Comment: Yeah you guys are right, would make more sense to just pick off the suffix. In this case it seems it can reliably be determined.

Also agree with the entrySet() optimization. Hmm, wonder if I can edit this to incorporate...

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum called MimeType with 2 String variables: extension and type. Create an appropriate constructor and pass in the ".xxx" and the "application/xxx" values. Create a method to do the lookup. You can use enums in switch.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention it: A direct equivalent to your code would not be using a map for direct lookup (since that would require each extension to have exactly 3 characters) but a for loop:

```
...
Map<String, String> extmap = GetExtensionMap();
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry: extmap.entrySet())
  if (fileName.endsWith(entry.getKey))
    return entry.getValue();
...
```

This solution works with extensions of any length but is less performant than the hash lookup of course (and slightly less performant than the original solution)

*The Algorithmic-Design-Guy solution*

A more performant way would be to implement a tree structure starting with the *last* character of the extension and storing the appropriate MIME types at the respective nodes. 
You could then walk down the tree starting with the last character of the file name. But this is probably an overkill ...