# c ideas on shrinking this function?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have this huge switch case with nested switch case statements in it that I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to clean up?

```
switch (datatype) {
    case STR:
    {
         switch(operation)
         {
              case EQUALS:
              {
                     /* perform str compare */
              }
              case NOTEQUALS:
              {
              }
              case LT:
              {
              }
              case GT:
              {
              }
              case GTE:
              {
              }
              case LTE:
              {
              }
              default:
                 break;
         }
         break;
    }
    case VER:
    {
         switch(operation)
         {
              case EQUALS:
              {
                     /* perform version compare */
              }
              case NOTEQUALS:
              {
              }
              case LT:
              {
              }
              case GT:
              {
              }
              case GTE:
              {
              }
              case LTE:
              {
              }
              default:
                 break;
         }
         break;
    }
    case INT:
    {
         /* same */
    }
    case FLOAT:
    {
         /* same */
    }
    /* ... more types ... */
    /* ... .......... ... */
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why it's necessary to shrink this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the values for the operation are contiguous, you could make a table of function pointers. In fact you could make a 2D table of function pointers with a separate function to handle each operation/type combination. e.g

```
// do some range checking on input params
// invoke the handler
handlers[datatype][operation]();
```

Comment: you might want to do some verification that `datatype` and `operation` are in the correct range, otherwise Bad Things will happen.

Comment: Actually modern compilers will convert large switches to jumptables automatically (and do the range checking of course)

Comment: @drhirsch: this isn't about performance, it's about making clean code.

Comment: This doesn't seem cleaner to me. It will be more opaque and more difficult to maintain. I don't think there is anything inherently wrong with the long switch statements.

Comment: @Kinopiko: I have to disagree. Tables of function pointers are one the best ways to make complex C code like this easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 5):

Create some tables (arrays) with pointers to functions in it. You can then look up `func[STR][EQUALS]` to make the appropriate call. The call would end up looking like this...

```
Func[datatype][operation]();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try [the command pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199646/long-list-of-if-statements-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

The `NOTEQUALS` case can always be written in terms of the `EQUALS` case; similarly `GTE` in terms of `LT` and `LTE` in terms of `GE`.  So make the outer switch in terms of the `operation`, and only three of those six cases will need to switch on the `datatype`.

Comment: Not always if you consider partial orderings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a big array of function pointers and then call the relevant function based upon indexing to the correct function pointer in the array.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered creatively using a series of function pointers and storing them in a struct?

do it right and you can mimic objects and do something this like:

```
bool someArbitraryFunction (dataType aDatatype, operations anOperation)
{
 someUnknownStruct.datatype = aDatatype;
 someUnknownStruct.operation = anOperation;
 return someUnknownStruct->doMath(1,2);
}
```

and then you can put all the needed math functions, enums, and structs in a header file somewhere.

cleans up the "meat" of the code, and makes the math portable (just import it wherever you need it).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cases can all return a simple boolean value, all six logic cases can be rewritten in terms of LT and EQUALS, like follows:

```
switch(operation) {
  case EQUALS:
    return isEquals();
  case NOTEQUALS:
    return !isEquals();
  case LT:
    return isLT();
  case GT:
    return !isLT() && !isEquals();
  case GTE:
    return !isLT();
  case LTE:
    reutrn isLT() || isEquals();
  default:
    break;
}
```

This would only require you to write the logic for isLT() and isEquals(), which would do the switching on datatype when necessary.  This eliminates a significant amount of unnecessary code duplication, yet doesn't sacrifice a lot of legibility.

This can be combined with function pointers as Stephen Doyle and rikh already suggested, which would eliminate the switch() statement entirely.