# How to use if-else statement with function returns?

Tags: java, coding-style, conditional-statements

I always try to avoid nested statements.

They lead me into putting code into a long curly braces. It becomes hard to follow the code when the amount of code with in each condition becomes larger.

```
if(condtion) {

} else if(condition2) {

} else {

}
```

So if I have code like this:

```
void doSomething(){  
    if(condtion) {
        return;
    } else if(condition2) {
        return;
    } else {
        return;
    }    
}
```

I always change it to this form (I avoided the `else` as there is a `return` statement from each condition):

```
void doSomething() {
    if(condtion) {
        return;
    }    
    if(condition2) {
        return;    
    }
    return;
}
```

But someone told me mine is a bit hard to read, which one is better?

Comment: Your question is hard to read. We don't need so much vertical whitespace. Some of us read SO on a mobile device.

Comment: Each one use for different purposes. There is a behavioural change in your codes. They are not the same to decide which is best practise.

Comment: I'm old school, I was taught that every function/method should have a single entry and exit point, to this end, the first would preferred.  Adding `return` statements within the `if-else if` blocks can mean that people can miss them and suddenly people don't know what's going on. The last can make it difficult to understand the relationship and logic you are trying to achieve (IMHO).  If your `if-else` blocks are running long, consider supplementing the functionality for methods `if (condition1) { doSomethingImportant(); }`

Comment: @AndyTurner I am updating it

Comment: If you have code like the second example, there is no need for the return statements: all branches return when they are done.

Comment: Why not use `switch` statement. If the `conditional` is not too complicated.

Comment: Replace conditional logic with polymorphism,Please read [this](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Comment: And also please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199646/long-list-of-if-statements-in-java),Command Design Pattern to replace the long list of if statements.

Comment: Could you take a look to [elegant-ways-to-handle-ifif-else-else](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122485/elegant-ways-to-handle-ifif-else-else)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If conditions are some quick-cases or preconditions, I prefer immediate `return` or `throw` without an `else` statement. For example:

```
void processArray(int[] array) {
    if(array == null || array.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Empty input");
        return;
    }
    // do some complex computations
}
```

This way the rest of your method which is the main course has no extra indent and no extra brace at the end which probably way below the `else` statement.

If conditional branches are quite long and has roughly the same length, then the code smells anyways. You need to refactor it extracting the branches to methods or (sometimes better) to separate classes using something like [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

**USUAL CASES:**

- If both results are same, all depends of person that reads the code.
- When method starts doing something more complex than checking simple conditions , it should have only one return statement.
- If logic of the method is really complex you must create various methods to clarify.

---

[Oracle Java Code Conventions 7.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html) does not mention about return inside if statements, but about if-else statements

### 7.4 if, if-else, if else-if else Statements

The if-else class of statements should have the following form:

```
if (condition) {
    statements;
}
```

```
if (condition) {
    statements;
} else {
    statements;
}
```

```
if (condition) {
    statements;
} else if (condition) {
    statements;
} else {
    statements;
}
```

So, according *ORACLE CONVENTIONS*, you must use `if-if else-else`, but you can choose between:

One single `return` statement

```
boolean doSomething(){  
    boolean var;
    if(condtion){
        var = false;
    }else if(condition2){
        var = true;
    }else{
        var = false;
    }    
    return var;
}
```

Or 3 `returns` statements.

```
boolean doSomething(){  
    if(condtion){
        return;
    }else if(condition2){
        return;
    }else{
        return;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You can have a return in a void function, but you don´t actually return anything.

Comment: mmm... I though IDE will complain.... agree... corrected, THANKS!

Comment: upvote for the USUAL CASES.

Answer (score 1):

> But someone told me mine is a bit hard to read, which one is better?

There is no "better".  The fact that someone told you that yours is hard to read, while obviously, you find yours easier to read, is testament to the fact that this is completely subjective.

You should do it the way it is easier for you.

Comment: But how about when working in team?

Comment: The team should be flexible enough to accept small variations in coding style, stemming from each developer's own preferences, and not mandate absolute conformity from everyone.  People should really just relax.

Comment: Now, if your workplace sees themselves as the Gestapo, then obviously, you have to abide by their wishes.  Quite possibly, while looking for a different job.

Comment: Liked your last comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if the amount of code with in each condition becomes larger, i'll do :

```
void doSomething()
{
    if (condtion)
    {
        function1();
    }
    else if (condition2)
    {
        function2();
    }
    else
    {
        function3();
    }
}
```

like this, i think it's a bit easier to read.