# How to optimize java function which has lot of if else statements in java?

Tags: java

I am a newbie and just started working on code, i have a task at hand and after doing a bit  of research i am still not able to find the answer.

I have a java function which uses a lot of if else statements, my task is to optimize the code since nest if else is not very good programming so i've been told.

First i thought switch statement is the way to go but then i came across people telling to use map, i don't know what map is and the examples online are very hard to even understand.

Here is the code i have to optimize

```
public static Boolean SurveyValidObject(JSONObject jSONObject) {

    Boolean message = false;

    if (jSONObject != null) {

        Iterator it = jSONObject.keys();
        ArrayList<String> keysList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            if (key.contains("field_")) {
                int i = key.indexOf("_");
                String _fieldValue = key.substring(0, i + 1);
                keysList.add(_fieldValue);
            } else {
                keysList.add(key);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<String> userDatalist = new ArrayList<String>();
        userDatalist.add("survey_id");
        userDatalist.add("source_id");
        userDatalist.add("sso_id");
        userDatalist.add("email_id");
        userDatalist.add("field_");

        Boolean returnValue = keysList.containsAll(userDatalist);

        Iterator iterator = jSONObject.keys();
        if (returnValue) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                try {

                    String key = (String) iterator.next(); // get key
                    String value = jSONObject.getString(key); // get value

                    if (key.equals("survey_id")) {

                        if (value == null) {
                            message = false;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            Boolean checkInteger = value.matches("\\d+");
                            if (!checkInteger) {
                                message = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (key.equals("crm_id")) {

                        if (value == null) {
                            message = false;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            Boolean checkInteger = value.matches("\\d+");
                            if (!checkInteger) {
                                message = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if (key.equals("source_id")) {
                        if (value == null) {
                            message = false;
                            break;

                        } else {
                            Boolean checkInteger = value.matches("\\d+");
                            if (!checkInteger) {
                                message = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (key.equals("sso_id")) {
                        if (value == null) {
                            message = false;
                            break;

                        } else {

                            Boolean checkId = value.matches("^[ A-Za-z0-9\\\"\\$%^&()!*:;<>?{}_@.\\/#+-/'']*$");
                            String compareSSOValue = "/";
                            if (!checkId || compareSSOValue.equals(value)) {
                                message = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (key.equals("email_id")) {
                        if (value == null) {
                            message = false;
                            break;

                        } else {

                            message = value.matches("\\b[\\w.%-'-]+@[-.\\w]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\\b");
                            if (!message) {
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    if (key.contains("field_")) {
                        int i = key.indexOf("_");
                        String _fieldValue = key.substring(i + 1);
                        Boolean checkInteger = _fieldValue.matches("\\d+");
                        if (checkInteger) {
                            message = true;
                        } else {
                            message = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: Try to use switch-case

Comment: So, are you trying to optimize performance (to which I would then ask if you know for a fact that you have a performance problem)?  Or are you trying to make the code more readable (pretty, elegant, concise, etc.)?  Those are 2 very different objectives.

Comment: By *optimize*, do you mean make it faster or more readable?

Comment: You have a `break` in both the inner `if` and the `else`. Since that means that the `break` has to be executed in either condition, you can move it outside.

Comment: first and foremost **remove code duplication**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199646/long-list-of-if-statements-in-java

Comment: A map is basically an object with two similarly sized collections. One collections holds the so called keys, and the other holds the values. You can perform a .get(key) on your map and it will return the associated value (the value on the same index(index in collection 1) in the other collection). Eg: Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>(); map.put(3,"three"); map.put(4,"four"); map.get(4) // Returns the string "four"; map.get(3) // Returns the string three. You can in theory see it as a tabel with in the left column the keys, and on the right values.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest (and most future-proof) option would be to pull all those checks out into their own place - I usually use an `enum` for that.

As you want to use a `String` to work out which check to make then we can make the `enum` build a `Map`.

```
static final Map<String, KeyCheck> lookup = new HashMap<>();

enum KeyCheck {

    SurveyId("survey_id"),
    CRMId("crm_id"),
    SourceID("source_id"),
    SSOId("sso_id") {
                @Override
                boolean check(String value) {
                    return value != null
                    && value.matches("^[ A-Za-z0-9\\\"\\$%^&()!*:;<>?{}_@.\\/#+-/'']*$")
                    && !value.equals("/");
                }
            },
    EMailId("email_id"){
                @Override
                boolean check(String value) {
                    return value != null
                    && value.matches("\\b[\\w.%-'-]+@[-.\\w]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\\b");
                }
            };

    KeyCheck(String key) {
        // All checks install in a Map.
        lookup.put(key, this);
    }

    // Default to just check not null & integer.
    boolean check(String value) {
        return value != null && value.matches("\\d+");
    }
}
```

Your loop then simplifies drastically:

```
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                try {

                    String key = (String) iterator.next(); // get key
                    String value = jSONObject.getString(key); // get value

                    KeyCheck check = lookup.get(key);
                    if (check != null) {
                        message = check.check(value);
                    }
                    // Do something else with this.
                    if (key.contains("field_")) {
                        int i = key.indexOf("_");
                        String _fieldValue = key.substring(i + 1);
                        Boolean checkInteger = _fieldValue.matches("\\d+");
                        if (checkInteger) {
                            message = true;
                        } else {
                            message = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {

                }
            }
```

BTW: Notice that you will change the value of `message` for all keys in the sequence so you are only actually checking the **last** key, not all of them. This may be a bug.

Comment: This is the best solution for a series of comparisons against a set of values known at compile time (+1).

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of code duplicates. If you refactor them, you could remove lot of the `if` statements.

**E.G**
`null` check for `value` is repeated in every `if` statement.

```
                    if (value == null) {
                        message = false;
                        break;
                    }
```

And the below `if` statement also repeated.

```
                   Boolean checkInteger = value.matches("\\d+");
                    if (!checkInteger) {
                        message = false;
                        break;
                    }
```

Instead of above repeated codes you could do the following.

```
                String key = (String) iterator.next(); // get key
                String value = jSONObject.getString(key); // get value

                if (value == null) {
                    return false; // return false and exit the method
                }

                Boolean checkInteger = value.matches("\\d+");

                if(key.equals("survey_id") || key.equals("crm_id")){
                    if (!checkInteger) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

**Likewise try to refactor the code isolating duplicates.**

Below is what I could achieve by removing duplicate code.

```
try {

    String key = (String) iterator.next(); // get key
    String value = jSONObject.getString(key); // get value

    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (key.equals("survey_id") || key.equals("crm_id") || key.equals("source_id")) {

        Boolean checkInteger = value.matches("\\d+");
        if (!checkInteger) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (key.equals("sso_id")) {

        Boolean checkId = value.matches("^[ A-Za-z0-9\\\"\\$%^&()!*:;<>?{}_@.\\/#+-/'']*$");
        String compareSSOValue = "/";
        if (!checkId || compareSSOValue.equals(value)) {
            message = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (key.equals("email_id")) {

        message = value.matches("\\b[\\w.%-'-]+@[-.\\w]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\\b");
        if (!message) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (key.contains("field_")) {
        int i = key.indexOf("_");
        String _fieldValue = key.substring(i + 1);
        Boolean checkInteger = _fieldValue.matches("\\d+");
        if (checkInteger) {
            message = true;
        } else {
            message = false;
            break;
        }
    }

} catch (org.json.JSONException e) {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In code above **two** places you can make more readable and can skip many `if-else` clauses:

1. In this place `if (jSONObject != null)` you can change it as

> ```
> if (jSONObject == null) {
>     return false;
> }
>
> // the rest of the code will goes here
> ```

And the same to  `if (returnValue)`

2. In the second `while` loop, I saw many times `if (value == null)`, you need check only once, then you can change it as below:

> ```
> while (iterator.hasNext()) {
>     try {
>         String key = (String) iterator.next(); // get key
>         String value = jSONObject.getString(key); // get value
>
>         if (value == null) {
>             // if the value was null, then directly break;
>             message = false;
>             break;
>          }
>            // then many if else clauses you can skip like:
>            if (key.equals("survey_id")) {
>                Boolean checkInteger = value.matches("\\d+");
>                if (!checkInteger) {
>                   message = false;
>                   break;
>                 }
>                 // no need for ths
>                 /*if (value == null) {
>                         message = false;
>                         break;
>                     } else {
>                         Boolean checkInteger = value.matches("\\d+");
>                         if (!checkInteger) {
>                             message = false;
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     }
> ```

```
                }*/
```

> ```
>          // the rest of the code goes here.
>          //...
>     }
> }
> ```

These 2 points that I suggested. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Is using `if (jSONObject == null)` more performant than `if (jSONObject != null)`?  Should the more common case go int the `if` block?